# How to see if no output from `ls *.xls` command?

Tags: bash, cron

Ubuntu 14.04.1.

I have a bash script, called by cron every 10 minutes, which basically looks for files in a subdir, then loops through and process each file. But how do I check if there are no files found? If there are no files found I don't want to process them, and I don't want to get an email via cron that says "no files found", because cron runs every 10 minutes. That's 144 emails per day saying "no files found" that I don't want to get.

- The input/ dir is owned by me and has full rwx permissions.
- I've already guaranteed the files in input/ do not contain spaces, thanks to another answer on Ask Ubuntu.

Here's my basic script.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Cron requires a full path in $myfullpath
myfullpath=/home/comp/progdir
files=`ls $myfullpath/input/fedex*.xlsx`
# How do I check for no files found here and exit without generating a cron email?
for fullfile in $files
do

done
```

Thanks! I didn't even know what to google for this one.

EDIT: My script is now this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script: gocronloop, Feb 5, 2015
# Cron requires a full path to the file.
mydir=/home/comp/perl/gilson/jimv/fedex
cd $mydir/input
# First remove spaces from filesnames in input/
find -name "* *" -type f | rename 's/ /-/g'
cd $mydir
shopt -s nullglob
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "ERROR in shopt"
    exit 1
fi
for fullfile in "$mydir"/input/fedex*.xlsx
    do
    # First remove file extension to get full path and base filename.
    myfile=`echo "$fullfile"|cut -d'.' -f1`
    echo -e "\nDoing $myfile..."
    # Convert file from xlsx to xls.
    ssconvert $myfile.xlsx $myfile.xls
    # Now check status in $?
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "ERROR in ssconvert"
        exit 1
    fi
    perl $1 $mydir/fedex.pl -input:$mydir/$myfile.xls -progdir:$mydir 
    done
```

Comment: @Rmana: `For fullfile in $myfullpath/input/fedex*.xlsx; do` Cron requires I specify a full path to the files I'm processing. Is this the right syntax for a glob? Thanks!

Comment: This is almost the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937407/test-whether-a-glob-has-any-matches-in-bash (hey, a cross-site-almost-duplicate!)

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs (re: programmatic use of `ls`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First things first: *Don't parse `ls`*.

Now that we have got that out of the way, use globbing, alongwith [`nullglob`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/NullGlob):

```
shopt -s nullglob
for fullfile in "$myfullpath"/input/fedex*.xlsx
do
#.......
done
```

Usually with globbing, if `*` doesn't match anything it's left as is. With `nullglob`, it is replaced with nothing, so a false match isn't triggered.

For example:

```
$ bash -c 'a=(foo/*); echo ${a[@]}'
foo/*
$ bash -c 'shopt -s nullglob; a=(foo/*); echo ${a[@]}'

$
```

Comment: Yep, better. ;-)

Comment: I'm getting an error in the cron email which says "shopt: not found" but when I run shopt at the command line I get output. When I do `which shopt` I get nothing, and there is no man page for shopt. Weird.

Comment: @Bulrush `shopt` is a shell builtin of `bash`. I was under the impression your script is using `bash`. What does the cron entry look like, i.e., how are you calling this script?

Comment: Cron entry: `0-59/10 * * * * /home/comp/perl/gilson/jimv/fedex/gocronloop` The cronloop is a bash script which I added to my original post above.

Comment: @Bulrush Ok, that is weird. Try forcing use `bash`: `0-59/10 * * * * bash /home/comp/perl/gilson/jimv/fedex/gocronloop`

Comment: Crap! I forgot the bang(!) before /bin/bash. Let me put the bang in and try it. You'd think the shell would look for that by now if #/bin/bash is in there. It's a common typo.

Comment: @muro, adding the shebang to #!/bin/bash in my gocronloop script worked. No more error emails from cron. Bash has a test mode to test scripts. Would the test mode find something like a missing shebang?

Comment: @Bulrush are you talking of `-x`? I don't know of any way to identify a incorrect shebang, since without the bang it is a comment.

Comment: @Bulrush, no, `!/bin/bash` is not something that `bash -n` would find, since it's not a syntax error -- it's a completely valid command (running `/bin/bash`, waiting for it to exit, and negating its exit status). Similarly, `#/bin/bash` is just a comment, and comments are valid syntax too. `#!/bin/bash` is read by the operating itself when deciding which interpreter to use, so as far as bash is concerned, it's just a comment.

Comment: @Bulrush You can try [`checkbashisms`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/checkbashisms.1). It throws this warning: `script test.sh does not appear to have a #! interpreter line;
you may get strange results`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're dead-set on using `ls` anyway, despite it's unsuitability for your original code, or if you:

### just want to find out if `ls` didn't find any files

you could check it's exit code. A "No such file..." will fail 
(exit code 2). While even an empty directory's `ls` will succeed (exit code 0):

```bash
$ ls *.xls
ls: cannot access *.xls: No such file or directory
$ echo $?
2

$ ls
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: No I don't have to use `ls`, as it appears ls generates an error msg if there are no files to process in input/, which generates a cron email, and I don't want cron emails filling my mail box every 10 minutes.

Comment: True. But this answers your question *"How to see if no output from `ls *.xls` command? / how do I check if there are no files found?"* Don't use `ls` as your original code does, but in case you want to first check if there are any files (for some other reason, you want a "yes/no files" answer, etc)

Comment: I appreciate your input, but I did learn that parsing `ls` is actually a serious problem. So in this case, I'd like to learn how to do it better, faster, stronger. :)

Comment: @Xen2050 It was indeed the one answer to the actual question I had, so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Python seems a comfortable option as well if I am not missing the point:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os

myfullpath = "/home/jacob/Bureaublad" 
files = [f for f in os.listdir(myfullpath) if f.endswith(".xlsx")]

for f in files:
    cmd = "gedit"
    subprocess.check_call(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd])
```

Comment: If you're not doing anything if len(files) is zero, you may omit that line/condition; `for f in files` will do nothing if `files` is empty; and `files` is guaranteed to be iterable due to it being defined as a list comprehension. One less line! \o/ Also, instead of `subprocess.popen`, I suggest using `subprocess.check_call` or `subprocess.check_output`; `Popen` semantics are more complicated than that, and you're bound to leak file descriptors and/or leave zombie processes around.

Comment: @roadmr completely right of course. It was a quick one to indicate `python` might have advantages in a case like this. Thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

Let `find` do the hard work for you. Write a script that processes a file passed as the first parameter, then do this in your crontab:

```
find /wherever  -iname 'fedex*.xls' -exec your-script "{}" \;
```

`find` will not generate any output if it doesn't find files matching the expression.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937407/test-whether-a-glob-has-any-matches-in-bash, something like that should work:

```
cd "$myfullpath/input/"

if test -n "$(shopt -s nullglob; echo fedex*.xlsl)"
then
    for file in fedex*.xlsl
    do 
          fullfile="$myfullpath/input/$file"
          # things
    done 
fi
```

... Look also at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Somebody should add `ls *` to a blacklist for questions and automatically redirect to that wiki page.

Comment: That doesn't look like bash syntax.

Comment: Rmano's snippet looks plenty like bash shellscript to me.

Comment: ...it's silly and inefficient (due to the subshell), and doesn't work in all corner cases (if you had filenames that contained only whitespace, this would deny that they existed), but it's certainly valid syntax. (If you wanted to _efficiently_ check on whether any files exist: `files=( fedex*.xls ); if (( ${#files[@]} )) && [[ -e $files ]] ; then echo "Files exist"; fi` -- no expensive subshell needed, and that's going to extra effort to work with nullglob either on or off).

Comment: Yep, @CharlesDuffy is correct, and muru answer is much better. I leave the answer just for the link to Greg's wiki ;-).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ if ! ls /tmp/*.bla >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then echo "no meat" ; else echo "have a steak" ; fi
no meat
$ touch /tmp/a.bla
$ if ! ls /tmp/*.bla >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then echo "no meat" ; else echo "have a steak" ; fi
have a steak
```

Comment: That's just a repeat of [a previous answer](/a/582018) without code formatting

Comment: @DavidFoerster I fail to see how this is a copy of any existing answers.

Comment: It checks the exit status of `ls` too, like my answer, only using an `if` statement (and somewhat unclear meat analogy)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the find command, putting a single filename on each line:

```
for fullfile in $(find <dir> -name '*.xslx'); do  
# fullfile now contains the full filename, including any spaces  
# process to your heart's content, using double quotes (") around $fullfile to  
#  make sure the spaces are kept intact  
    cp "$fullfile" /new/directory/  
end
```

Comment: For the same reason I say "Don't parse ls."

Comment: `find` goes together well with `xargs`, especially the null-terminated options, see `man find` or `man xargs`